# SendKeys in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, keyboard, sendkeys, keystroke

Is there a possibility to use the function SendKeys in a Silverlight5 application? 
Because I want to simulate the "Key.Right" in my application.

Comment: Can you give me a sample code for a SendKeys in Silverlight? Or is it not possible like its said in that post...
"There is no sendkey feature for silverlight as far as I know."

Comment: @user1586660 - unfortunately there is no SendKeys in Silverlight, you'll need to use UI Automation, but there are a number of blog posts listed there that will give you some good examples.

Comment: Ok, I'll try some of them.